# Marking statement as side-effect free for tree shaking

Tags: webpack, tree-shaking

I have a package with ESM exports, with exported functions that have **properties** on them:

```js
function Foo() { return 'Foo' }
Foo.displayName = 'Foo'

function Qux() { return 'Qux' }
Qux.displayName = 'Qux'

function Bar() { return 'Bar' + Qux() }
Bar.displayName = 'Bar'

export { Bar, Foo }
```

And importing only `Foo` in my app:

```js
import { Foo } from 'pkg1'

console.log(Foo)
```

when compiling with webpack production mode, `Qux` is **also included**  in the bundle, **unless** `Qux.displayName = 'Qux'` is removed. `Bar` isn't included.

Both package.jsons have `"sideEffects": false`.

Is there a way to tell webpack/terser that this statement is side-effect free?

Example repo: https://github.com/elado/tree-shaking-issue

Adding a **PURE** doesn't work on statements, only function calls.

```js
Qux.displayName = /*@__PURE__*/ 'Qux' // doesn't work
```

A few not-ideal solutions...

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  Qux.displayName = 'Qux'
}
```

or marking `Object.assign` function call as pure:

```js
// Qux.js
/*@__PURE__*/ Object.assign(Qux, { displayName: 'Qux' })
```